# Point Clustering in QGIS, but values show a percentage and not count of points

Tags: qgis, point, symbology, clustering

I am utilising mobility location data of common evening points from a Geofenced area to determine the trade area of a specific shopping centre.

To visualise this for the clients, I need to group together the points and show how many common evening points fall within the trade area. This seems to confuse the client, see map below.

[image]

Here is the map with out point clustering:
[image]

Now to make this clearer for the client we decided it would be best if we indicated the percentage of people with their common evening points. But in QGIS there doesn't seem to be a way to do this quickly with Point Clustering to show this count as a percentage of the total rather than just the count.

I have made this map below, but this is based on a new shapefile I created and manually calculated the percentages.

Please advise.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The displayed number is part of the point clustering symbol.

To modify it, click on the cluster symbol:
[image]

Then select the `font marker` and click the epsilon for the character data override:

[image]

Edit it and enter the following expression:

```
round(@cluster_size / count('')  * 100.0,2) || ' %'
```

`@cluster_size` is the point count
`count('')` is the total number of features in the layer
`round( ... , 2)` will keep only 2 decimals
`|| ' %'` will append the % sign after the computed value

[image]